# Safari not implementing "width: calc(...);"

Tags: css, safari

On Windows, all my browsers respect:

```
.entry-header {
    margin-left: calc((100% - 1070px)/2);
}
```

Safari 10.0.3 on Mac does not, giving margin-left a blank value I think.

How can I resolve this for Safari/Mac please?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are we going to guess the version of the browser? http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some other css overriding that?

Comment: spaces are important `calc((100% - 1070px) / 2)` also, see css variables for another solution